# Cannot get the proper first value

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have a query where I want to grab the first transaction time a package was scanned into a HAZ location as written in the following query:

```
SELECT 
LOCATION, 
COUNT(PACKAGE_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY LOCATION) AS PACKAGE_COUNT,
PACKAGE_ID,
(TRUNC(SYSDATE)-TRUNC(DATE_RECEIVED)) AS DAYS_AGED,
ORDER_NUMBER
FROM
    (SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    LOCATION, 
    PACKAGE_ID,
    ORDER_NUMBER,
    FIRST_VALUE(TRAN_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PACKAGE_ID ORDER BY TRAN_DATE) AS DATE_RECEIVED
    FROM    
        (SELECT
        (CASE WHEN SPM.PARENT_PACKAGE_ID IS NULL THEN SPM.PACKAGE_ID ELSE SPM.PARENT_PACKAGE_ID END) AS PACKAGE_ID, 
        SUBSTR(SPM.ORDER_NUMBER,1,5) AS ORDER_NUMBER,
        SPM.LOCATION AS LOCATION,
        PL.TRAN_DATE AS TRAN_DATE
        FROM SO_PACKAGE_MASTER SPM
        INNER JOIN PACKAGE_LOG PL ON PL.PACKAGE_ID = SPM.PACKAGE_ID
        WHERE SPM.LOCATION LIKE '%HAZ%'
        AND PL.DESTINATION LIKE '%HAZ%'
        AND SPM.SHIPPED = 'N'
        AND SPM.STATUS = 'C'))
ORDER BY LOCATION, DAYS_AGED DESC, PACKAGE_ID;
```

I get the following data set:

```
HAZOUT-01   13  1894980 254 04591
HAZOUT-01   13  1895207 158 04591
HAZOUT-01   13  1510372 85  28236
HAZOUT-01   13  1510374 85  28236
HAZOUT-01   13  1510535 85  28237
HAZOUT-01   13  1510537 85  28237
HAZOUT-01   13  1812277 36  MSR00
HAZOUT-01   13  1816943 29  22062
HAZOUT-01   13  1816947 29  22062
HAZOUT-01   13  1852815 28  27677
HAZOUT-01   13  1855792 28  27764
HAZOUT-01   13  1902199 2   22065
HAZOUT-01   13  1902202 2   22065
```

but if I look in my package_log table for 1894980 it does not show that it was there 254 days:

```
1894980 HAZOUT-01   15-MAR-18
```

Any idea why?(system date is current date EST)

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking for the first value by package id.  If that is what you want, then include it in the `partition by`:

```
SELECT PL.PACKAGE_ID, PL.DESTINATION,
       FIRST_VALUE(PL.TRAN_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PL.PACKAGE_ID ORDER BY PL.TRAN_DATE) AS DATE_RECEIVED
FROM SO_PACKAGE_MASTER SPM INNER JOIN
     PACKAGE_LOG PL
     ON PL.PACKAGE_ID = SPM.PACKAGE_ID
WHERE PL.DESTINATION LIKE '%HAZ%' AND
      SPM.SHIPPED = 'N' AND
      SPM.STATUS = 'C';
```

I am not sure if you also want `DESTINATION` in the `PARTITION BY` as well.

Your query is returning the first value by `DESTINATION`.

By the way, you might as well use `MIN()` for this logic:

```
SELECT PL.PACKAGE_ID, PL.DESTINATION,
       MIN(PL.TRAN_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PL.PACKAGE_ID) AS DATE_RECEIVED
FROM SO_PACKAGE_MASTER SPM INNER JOIN
     PACKAGE_LOG PL
     ON PL.PACKAGE_ID = SPM.PACKAGE_ID
WHERE PL.DESTINATION LIKE '%HAZ%' AND
      SPM.SHIPPED = 'N' AND
      SPM.STATUS = 'C';
```

I see no reason to use `FIRST_VALUE()` instead.

Comment: Ok this is how I originally had it but it gets more complicated,  I can post my full query, but it doesnt calculate the right days from today to transaction date in package_log.